# Table of contents shows up in hyperlinked document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table of contents that i have used to access documents in a manual using hyperlinks. However, when i click on the document in the TOC, the TOC shows up in the document itself. If i scroll up or down and click on the document, the TOC that was in that document disappears. This only happens to documents that are 2 or more pages. Anyway to get rid of this happening?